# Separable metric spaces that are not normable

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Not quite sure whether this question belongs here or on [MESE](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/). Anyway: Can anyone suggest a good example of a separable metric space that is neither normable nor a subset of normed space with the induced metric? Anything less trivial than a discrete metric space would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

All metric spaces are subspaces of a Banach space. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski_embedding for instance.

If your metric space is separable you can even embed it in $\mathcal{C}([0.1],\mathbb{R})$ with the usual sup norm.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. In which sense is, say, the discrete metric space built upon the set $\{\{1\},\{2\},\{NYC\}\}$ a subspace of a Banach space?

Comment: It's homeomorphic to the subspace $\{1,2,3\}$ of the Banach space $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Of course, but the metric distance has nothing to do with the distance induced by $|\cdot|$, so the analogy looks rather misleading to me.

Comment: If you give me the distance between the three points I can give you three points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that have the same relative distances. In general any separable metric space is isometric to a subset of $\mathcal{C}([0;1])$ equipped with the sup norm.

Comment: Ok, but you were talking about sub*spaces* of a Banach space, and $\{1,2,3\}$ is definitely no subspace of anything. Plus, Kuratowski's theorem states imbeddability in $C(X)$ of any metric space $X$, which is quite different from imbeddability in $C([0,1])$. (And besides, of course if I am asking for elementary examples I am not interesting in something that relies upon Kuratowski's theorem...)

Comment: There is a confusion on the word "subspace" : I'm saying "subspace" as in "subspace of a topological space", so it's just a subset. The Kuratowski embedding allows you to embed any metric space in a Banach space, and then any separable Banach space can be embedded in $\mathcal{C}([0.1])$. But most importantly, what I'm saying is that there are no examples. You're looking for a metric space that is not a subset of a normed space, and that doesn't exist by those theorems.

Comment: I strongly doubt that if you start with, say, $2^\mathbb R$, your reasoning works.

Comment: @Delio: Your doubts are irrelevant, I’m afraid: Kuratowski’s theorem and the [Banach-Mazur theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Mazur_theorem) dispose of them completely.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Ok, let me be more precise: 1) the answer states that "all metric spaces are subspaces of a Banach space": in my example of the discrete metric space $X:=2^\mathbb R$ (or even just $X:=\mathbb R$...) Kuratowski's theorem simply states that $X$ can be isometrically imbedded in $C_b(2^{\mathbb R})$ (resp., $C_b(\mathbb R)$); since these spaces are not separable, I don't see how to apply the Banach-Mazur theorem then.

Comment: @Delio: Since those spaces are not separable, they have nothing to do with your original question or with the statement in the second paragraph of this answer.

Comment: These spaces are already Banach spaces. The Banach-Mazur theorem is just a bonus that says that under some hypotheses there is a space that always works.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott That said, once again: my question is of didactic nature. I'm asking for objects whose nature can be seen more or less directly, without going through imbeddings guaranteed by theorems which of course have not yet been introduced at an early stage of a course.

Comment: @Delio: You’re asking for objects that don’t exist.

Comment: @DelioMugnolo $2^\mathbb{R}$ *is* separable, just not metrisable.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I've said that $C_b(2^{\mathbb R})$ is not separable (since $2^{\mathbb R})$ is not compact), I was not talking about $2^{\mathbb R}$.